# How to use variable from component to be published in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a validation component to be published.
Just like vee-validate I want to use a variable this.$validate.bla() ?
where bla is function in my component.

Comment: https://github.com/yogeshgalav/vue-form-mixin

Comment: Should it be like declaring and alternative variable to $ref['mycomponent']. 
Please help me with concept.

Comment: Also can I use  document.getElementsByName() inside component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main file:

```
import Validate from 'your_validation_module';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$Validate', {
    value: Validate
});
```

then use like this in your code :

```
this.$Validate.blah()
```

in Vue3 you should use Provide/Inject , [app level provide](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#app-level-provide)

Comment: I can't use it everywhere, Can I define $validate inside component?

Comment: If not work in component, you can assign it to a component property on "component create" , but I think if you define it globally in main file, it will work in template as well.